# Publish/Web Deploy for Mac Visual Studio Community

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, publish, webdeploy, visual-studio-mac

Is there a way to Publish ASP.NET Core WebApp to a local folder and not just the forced default to Azure? I looked around and can't find any information on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to Publish ASP.NET Core WebApp to a local folder and not just the forced default to Azure?

I test it on the windows platform via [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) commandline, it works correctly. You could have a try on Mas OS.

```
dotnet publish webprojectName.csproj --output localpath
```

[image]